# Micropython on ESP8266 creates files with null character in name

Tags: esp8266, micropython

I'm a raw beginner working with an ESP8266.

I created a file main.py containing this code:

```
f = open( 'f.dat', 'w')
print( 'a', file=f )
f.close()
```

When I run

```
ampy -pCOM3 put main.py main.py
```

main.py runs immediately, and creates 128 files with the same name, which is 8 null characters before the dot and 3 null characters after.

Running

```
ampy -pCOM3 ls
```

displays 128 lines of "        .   "
and from a terminal emulator,

```
os.listdir()
```

shows this 128 times:
    '\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00.\x00\x00\x00'

Can anyone explain what's happening, and how to prevent it? and tell me how to delete the files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
print( 'a', file=f )
```

... try this:

```
f.write('a')
```

...based on information found [here](http://docs.micropython.org/en/v1.8.2/esp8266/esp8266/tutorial/filesystem.html).

Comment: Thank you, that prevents the problem.  The `print` stmt causes the problem when run from AMPY, but not in a terminal emulator.  I'm finding MicroPython quite confusing, in this case and many others.

Comment: `ampy` is not part of MicroPython, it's 3rd-party utility.